# Sort files in SDcard by date created

Tags: android

I need to sort files from sdcard folder by date created in android,i have saved files in sdcard folder using system date,can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: `public long lastModified ()`  [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

use a Collection.sort:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<File>() {
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        long lastModifiedO1 = o1.lastModified();
        long lastModifiedO2 = o2.lastModified();

        return (lastModifiedO1 < lastModifiedO2) ? -1 : ((lastModifiedO1 > lastModifiedO2) ? 1 : 0);
    }
});
```

Check for typo

Answer (score 1):

Collection sort is the way to go as the others are suggesting.

Used this code awhile ago :

```
        Collections.sort(mFileList, new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            return Long.valueOf(f2.lastModified()).compareTo(
                    f1.lastModified());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Date of file one by one  :

```
File f= new File(filePath);
Date fileDate= new Date(f.lastModified());
```

And than Apply the Sorting Algorithm.

You'll achieve what you need