# How to sort SDCard image based on date in android

Tags: android, sorting, gridview

i am trying to sort the sdcard image into gridview baseed on date. i tried with variety of codes. But i cant able to achieve this. Please Provide me some help.

```
public class Sdcard extends Activity {

//  Cursor used to access the results from querying for images on the SD card.

private Cursor cursor;

 // Column index for the Thumbnails Image IDs.

private int columnIndex;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sdcard);

    // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

    GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


}
```

// Image adapter to link images to the gridview

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
        context = localContext;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView picturesView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            picturesView = new ImageView(context);
            // Move cursor to current position
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get the current value for the requested column
            int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
            picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
            picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            picturesView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        }
        else {
            picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }
        return picturesView;
    }
}
```

}

Thius code is working fine in emulator and does not working in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to sort files from a path base on lastmodified date

```
    File sd = new File(**pathofimagesfiles**);
    File[] sdFileList = sd.listFiles();
    if (sdFileList != null && sdFileList.length > 1) {
        Arrays.sort(sdFileList, new Comparator<File>() {
             @Override
             public int compare(File object1, File object2) {
                return object1.lastModified() - object2.lastModified();
             }
        });
    }
```

This may help !

Comment: Hi, i am new to this concept. Can you give me full coding?

Comment: @bala What do you need ?

Comment: i want to get all image from mobile and sd card . and all these images should be arranged by date wise. can u provide me sample coding

Answer (score 0):

use can use below code. worked for me. for Descending

```
final File[] files= file.listFiles();
if (files != null && files.length > 1) {
            Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(files), new Comparator<File>() {
                public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                    long lastModifiedO1 = o1.lastModified();
                    long lastModifiedO2 = o2.lastModified();

                    return (lastModifiedO2 < lastModifiedO1) ? -1 : ((lastModifiedO1 > lastModifiedO2) ? 1 : 0);
                }
            });
        }
```

for Ascending
refere 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065704/8416317